# What is the difference between Set keys() and Set keyset() in Hashtable in Java?

Tags: java, collections, hashtable

I am learning Collection Framework on this website: http://way2java.com/collections/hashtable-about/. After reading all the methods of `Hashtable` I see two methods to access the table's keys:

1. `Set keys()`: Returns a `Set` object containing all the keys
2. `Set keySet()`: Returns a `Set` object containing all the keys of `Hashtable`. One similarity is `Hashtable` and `Set` does not allow duplicates. Adding and removing elements in `Set` also reflects in `Hashtable`

Both of them return a `Set` object. I don't see the different between them. Anyone can tell me about this?

Comment: Don't learn from there. It looks like it's outdated, especially if it's teaching you the obsolete `Hashtable` class. Use `HashMap` instead, it's defined better too. Note the comment that `Hashtable` is a `Legacy class introduced in Java 1.0`.

Comment: [`keys()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#keys()) doesn't return a `Set`, it returns an `Enumeration<K>`.

Comment: This website is very good logic..so i like it, i learn Hashtable because i want know how the different between HashMap and Hashtable.

Comment: @Andy Brown: OHHH.. This Website make the mistake.

Comment: @QuanNguyen, they did indeed - always check the oracle docs: they are the authority. I have explained more fully in my answer.

Comment: I wouldn't only rely on a reference while trying to learn something like Collections, if you don't try it yourself you will never learn, and you will end up asking questions like this!

Comment: @QuakeCoreL thanks for remind, it's good for me.

Comment: @QuanNguyen How do you like the website's logic now?

Comment: @Kayaman: Author of this website have many of years in traning, so he give many of the different and similar between classes. help me to have good look about the lesson. you know?

Comment: @QuanNguyen Do as you wish, but personally I wouldn't read any sites that give out false and outdated information.

Comment: @Kayaman: Sometime, site give out false, but it make me never forget. and the importance is logical of this website..!! Can you give me a website in which you have learned before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`keys()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#keys()) doesn't return a `Set`, it returns an `Enumeration<K>`.

`Hashtable` is a very legacy class no longer recommended for use. It is replaced by `HashMap`, or `ConcurrentHashMap` <sup>†</sup>. It existed before the JCF did, therefore the standard way to get to the keys at the start was through an `Enumeration` - the original Java interface for moving through a collection of objects.

Then came Java 1.2, and the [JCF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html). `Hashtable` was retrofitted for the [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface with the [`keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet()) method that returned a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) (also introduced with the JCF). The `keys` method was retained for legacy compatibility reasons. The `Set` returned from the new method achieves two things:

1. conveys intent - it reinforces the fact that the keys of a `Hashtable` are a mathematical set
2. implements `Iterable<T>`, which replaces `Enumerable<T>`

<sup>†</sup> From the [`Hashtable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) documentation:

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the Map interface, making it a member of the  Java Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations, Hashtable is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use HashMap in place of Hashtable. If a thread-safe highly-concurrent implementation is desired, then it is recommended to use ConcurrentHashMap in place of Hashtable.

Answer (score 1):

The method [keys()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#keys()) in Hashtable actually return Enumeration of keys:

```
  Enumeration<K>    keys()
```

Returns an enumeration of the keys in this hashtable.

Answer (score 1):

[`Hashtable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) is an old, outdated, class that existed in Java before the introduction of the [standard collections framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html) in Java 1.2(!), and was retrofitted to adhere to the [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface.

`keys()` existed in the original `Hashtable` and returns an [`Enumaration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) of keys. `keySet()` is more modern method that was introduced in the `Map` interface and returns a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of the keys.